# hidden input in JSP returns null in the Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, input, hidden

this is the form in my jsp:

```
    <form id="withdrawFromAccountForm" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ActionServlet" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        <input type="hidden" name="jspId" value="viewClientDetails" /> 
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Enter" />

    </form>
```

And this is the code in my servlet:

```
String whatJsp = request.getParameter("jspId");     
if (whatJsp.equals("viewClientDetails"))
    {
        //code ..
    }
```

when I hit the submit button in the JSP, the servlet goes to the if sentence that checks
if the jsp is "viewClientDetails" jsp with the hidden input, but that input gives null ...

Is anyone see where the problem is ?
Thanks.

Comment: How are you reading that input? Please, show how `whatJsp` is initialized.

Comment: I edited it. Now you can see.

Comment: Why are you using `enctype="text/plain"` in your `<form>`?

Comment: OK I just removed enctype="text/plain" and it worked ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be here:

```html
<form ... enctype="text/plain">
          ^ here
```

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp):

> The enctype attribute specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server.
>
> text/plain: Spaces are converted to "+" symbols, but no special characters are encoded

Probably your server doesn't recognize or cannot parse the attributes when using this `enctype`. Remove it or use the default value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for it.